# Getting array from Foursquare with getJSON and store as variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, api, foursquare

ok, I am working with Foursquare's API, and I can get anything that has a single item in it pretty easily. So I can grab the name, number, rating, etc...

The problem I am having is getting anything that is in an array. In other words, if there is more than one item, I can't figure out how to return all of them.
so this is what the code looks like:

```
<script>
function getinfo(venueAPI) {
            $.getJSON(venueAPI, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                name = data.response.venue.name;
                phone = data.response.venue.contact.formattedPhone;
                $('#content').empty().append('<h1>' + name + '</h1>', b, '<a href="tel:' + phone + '">' + phone + '</a>');
            });
        }
</script>
```

The 'venueAPI' string is the API endpoint for the business I am looking up.

I've tried using $.each, and I've been searching around google like a crazy person trying to solve this.

To recap, I am trying to grab an array from Foursquare (photos, comments, etc) and store it in a string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the API call that is triggered with the getinfo function: onclick="getinfo('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4fd9e1f9d5fb0913decc6c9c?oauth_token=YCCKUVRO4J4MZQ121E4VTNHBRM4YH0FAVROW0KQ2OSJ32GRV&v=20141012');"

And here is the json that returns: [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=NsDgJvuQ)

Updated code:

```
 b = '<br/>';

        function getinfo(venueAPI) {
            $.getJSON(venueAPI, function(data) {
               $(function() {

                  var arr = [];
                   var photoarr = [];

          function getinfo() {
                console.log(data);
                arr = data.response.venue;
                $('#content').append(arr.id + '<br/>');
                $('#content').append(arr.name + '<br/>');
                photoarr = arr.photos.groups[0].items;
                photoarrlength = arr.photos.groups[0].items.length;
                console.log(photoarr);
                console.log(photoarrlength);
                $('#content').append('<br/> PHOTOS  <br/>');
                for (var i = 0; i < photoarrlength ; i++) {
                $('#content').append(photoarr[i].id + '<br>');
                }
                }
          getinfo();    
});
            });
        }
```

This returns:

4fd9e1f9d5fb0913decc6c9c
Eventide Oyster Co.

PHOTOS 
51db48a5498eb7682980e774
5071c5b2e4b0559b4dfd60b5
51cdc340498ed3d72134074f
51c9de9e498e6be2f81a19ba
50ecc042e4b0e13343ad9549
51d09fa8498efa529e38b2a5

which is the info I needed. Now I just need to make sure I can replicate this and understand what it's doing for the other values I need to grab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls provide an example call.

One option to achieve this could be to determine the array length and then use a for - loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Using jquery, check jQuery.each().

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Edit:

**Example:**

foursquare api call:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=Berlin&oauth_token=YOUR_OATH_KEY&v=20141018

response here:

http://lab.sourcloud.com/stackoverflow/26435383/response.js

Bascially this is what you have to do within the callback function from getJSON.

```
$(function() {
var data = response;
var arr = [];

function getinfo() {
                //console.log(data.response.groups[0].items);
                arr = data.response.groups[0].items;
                arrlength = data.response.groups[0].items.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrlength ; i++) {
                $('#content').append(arr[i].venue.name + '<br/>');
                }
        }
getinfo();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/wmpfu50w/

**Answer based on your JSON response:**

Check the For - loop.

```
$(function() {
var data = josh;
var arr = [];
var photoarr = [];

    function getinfo() {
                    console.log(data);
                    arr = data.response.venue;
                    $('#content').append(arr.id + '<br/>');
                    $('#content').append(arr.name + '<br/>');
                    photoarr = arr.photos.groups[0].items;
                    photoarrlength = arr.photos.groups[0].items.length;
                    console.log(photoarr);
                    console.log(photoarrlength);
                    $('#content').append('<br/> PHOTOS  <br/>');
                    for (var i = 0; i < photoarrlength ; i++) {
                    $('#content').append(photoarr[i].id + '<br>');
                    }
            }
    getinfo();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/tgwvwfrg/

**EDIT 3 (based on your answer, code cleanup)**

```
function getinfo(venueAPI) {
       $.getJSON(venueAPI, function(data) {   
               var arr = [];
               var photoarr = [];
               arr = data.response.venue;
               $('#content').append(arr.name +'<br/>');
               photoarr = arr.photos.groups[0].items;
               photoarrlength = arr.photos.groups[0].items.length;
               $('#content').append('<br/> PHOTOS  <br/>')
                   for (var i = 0; i < photoarrlength; i++) {
                       $('#content').append(
                           '<img src="' +
                           photoarr[i].prefix +
                           photoarr[i].width +
                           'x' + photoarr[i].height +
                           photoarr[i].suffix +
                           '">');
                   }
       });
 }
```

Comment: Here's a pastebin with an example of the json I get back: [link](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=NsDgJvuQ)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it sorted out, and I can replicate the code with any of the other items I need to get. You're a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code after bnz helped me with the right answer. It grabs all the public photos from a venue and displays them:

```
   function getinfo(venueAPI) {
       $.getJSON(venueAPI, function(data) {
           $(function() {
               var arr = [];
               var photoarr = [];

               function getinfo() {
                   console.log(data);
                   arr = data.response.venue;
                   $('#content').append(arr.name +
                       '<br/>');
                   photoarr = arr.photos.groups[0].items;
                   photoarrlength = arr.photos.groups[
                       0].items.length;
                   console.log(photoarr);
                   console.log(photoarrlength);
                   $('#content').append(
                       '<br/> PHOTOS  <br/>');
                   for (var i = 0; i <
                       photoarrlength; i++) {
                       $('#content').append(
                           '<img src="' +
                           photoarr[i].prefix +
                           photoarr[i].width +
                           'x' + photoarr[i].height +
                           photoarr[i].suffix +
                           '">');
                   }
               }
               getinfo();
           });
       });
   }
```

Comment: check my edited answer, i did a cleanup of your code. jqready, getinfo() does not make sense in that case. good luck with your project.